# Python: PIL: colors data type, need help "deciphering" its meaning

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I need help to understand the PIL and colors information a little bit better.

I'm working on a Python project where I'm supposed to analyze an already existing image (.png, RGB) to extract what colors are represented in that specific image.

I'm new to Python as well as the PIL, and I think I've extracted the color information in the image by:

```
image = Image.open("image.png")
image.getcolors(4000)
```

What I'm presented with is a list of tuples, and according to the documentation every tuple is representing one color (first integer is the number of times the color exists in the image, and then there is the actual color).

Extract from the output:

```
..., (44, (72, 64, 55, 255)), (32, (231, 208, 141, 255)), (2368, (70, 64, 55, 255)), 
(1, (187, 210, 216, 255)), (256, (68, 64, 57, 255)), (592, (67, 80, 103, 255)), 
(2, (198, 204, 214, 255), ...
```

What I don't get is what the numbers that are supposed to represent the color actually means. I'm thinking RGB, but there are four numbers. If it really is RGB, what is the last number (mostly 255 in almost every case)?

Any help in educating me in this matter is greatly appreciated. I've browsed the documentation and searched through the web, but I can't find any information on this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's [RGBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_space) (red green blue alpha).

The alpha channel is normally used as an opacity channel. If a pixel has a value of 0 in its alpha channel, it is fully transparent (and, thus, invisible), whereas a value of 255 in the alpha channel gives a fully opaque pixel.